# Rejoining SP 2016 server back to farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, configuration-wizard

I removed the SP server from farm using central admin option(Remove Server).Now when i am unable to rejoin the server.Getting below error Message while running product configuration wizard.

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException
> was thrown.  Additional exception information: Cannot perform security
> configuration because the configuration database does not exist.  You
> must create or join to a configuration database before doing security
> configuration"

Answer (score 1):

Removing from Central Admin is the forceful way of doing so -- it leaves the server you removed tattooed with the information about the farm, thus the server itself thinks it is still part of the farm but obviously cannot contact it.

You should instead build a new VM to replace it; you *could* try uninstalling SharePoint but this isn't the clean method I would take.'

If you have to remove a server from a farm and intend to rejoin it at a later time, use the Config Wizard on that farm member.